# if prototypes can't access private variables, what's the best way to "clean up" the code?

Tags: javascript, prototype, scoping

Hey guys, what i have now is this:

```
var Human=function(){
  this._a=Math.random();
};
(function() {
  var before_get = function(human) {
  };
  var before_set = function(human, v) {
  };
  Human.prototype={
    get A(){
      before_get(this);
      return this._a;
    },
    set A(v){
      before_set(this, v);
      this._a=v;
    }
  };
})();
alert(new Human().A); // test
alert(new Human().A); // test
```

and all's good except that i do not wish to expose the variable **_a** to anywhere else except the prototype. Ok i've did some searching and realised that that's not possible so I was wondering do we usually leave it as such (i mean do we just leave those _a variables flying around or is there a better solution)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as private in JavaScript, so this is not achievable. In general we do not have generic properties or setter/getters like other C#/Java have.

A pattern that can be used is closures instead of prototypes.

```
var Human = function() {
    var a = Math.random();
    var o = {};
    Object.defineProperties(o, {
        "A": {
             "get": function() {
                 return a;
             }, 
             "set": function(val) {
                 a = val;
             }
        }
    });
    return o;
}
```

In general though you shouldnt write properties to the prototype. The prototype should contain methods.

The only way to clean up `this._a` is as follows

```
var Human = (function() {
  var Human=function(){
    this._a=Math.random();
  };
  var before_get = function(human) {
  };
  var before_set = function(human, v) {
  };
  Human.prototype={
    getA(){
      before_get(this);
      return this._a;
    },
    setA(v){
      before_set(this, v);
      this._a=v;
    }
  };
  return function(args) {
     var h = new Human(args);
     return {
       getA: h.getA.bind(h),
       setA: h.setA.bind(h)
     }
  }
})();
```

Comment: but the problem with this method is that if i have 9999 Humans, i end up creating 9999 getters and 9999 setters..

Comment: @Pacerier that is true. But that is the only way to get a local variable for each of those 9999 humans. If each human need its own variable then each human needs a function with a reference to that variable.

Comment: @Raynos in my example (above) each human has its own variable, and all humans share a function with a reference to that variable (the beauty of the "this" variable). However the problem i have is that i could not find a way to expose variables only to the prototype and nothing else.. and thus i end up having those ugly "private" variables which are not so private.. so i was seeking a solution for it..

Comment: @Pacerier what you are asking for is _impossible_. The best you can do is return a proxy that does not publicly expores `this._a`

Comment: @Raynos heys what do you mean by a proxy, maybe this is what i want!

Comment: @Pacerier a proxy is a just a thin layer ontop of your object. Look at the edited answer. I'm returning an object that only exposes the property `A` and not `_a`. It's basically a middle man saying "You want A I can give you A, you want _a ? What is _a ?"

Comment: @Raynos heys i've tried the example, but I had a problem when i tried h.A.bind i had an exception (in chrome and firefox)

Comment: @Raynos seems like there's no way to access the "property function" because doing a h.A returns the value (which is the int)

Comment: @Pacerier Oh bah. That's what you get for using setter & getters. Use methods! It would work with `getA()` and `setA()`. Problem fixed/solved/gone !

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you create the likes of a private/static variables using prototypal 'inheritance'. The trick is to define the prototype methods within the constructor (once). The price is getters/setters you have to execute. The profit is simplicity and a true prototypal solution (which after all is the real nature of the beast). And btw, here you create your 'getter/setter' only once, and it's there for all 999(999) instances you create from it.

```
function Human() {
    var  a = 'We are all Human',
         o = {}
         proto = Human.prototype;
    if (!proto.A) {
       //uncomment and create a few instances to see
       //this is only executed once
       //console.log('adding prototypes');
       proto.A = function() {return a;};
       proto.set = function(val) {a = val || a;};
       proto.setName = function(val) {this.name = val || ''};
       proto.getName = function(){
           if (!this.name) {this.setName('no name yet');}
           return this.name;};
    }
}

var Pete = new Human,
    Jean = new Human;

console.log(Pete.A()+':'+Jean.A()); 
      //|=> We are all Human:We are all Human
Pete.set(Pete.A()+' except Jean'));
console.log(Pete.A()+':'+Jean.A()); 
      //|=> We are all Human except Jean:We are all Human except Jean
Pete.setName('Hi, I am Pete. '+Pete.A());
Jean.setName('Hi, I am Jean. ' +Jean.A()+ '. Damn! thats me!');
console.log(Pete.name); 
      //|=> Hi, I am Pete. We are all Human except Jean
console.log(Jean.name); 
      //|=> Hi, I am Jean. We are all Human except Jean. Damn! thats me!
```

You have to realize that anyone can decide to assign something else to `Human.prototype.A`. But if they do that outside the constructor, the closure, and therefore `a`, is not available anymore.

Comment: What have you have there is static and private. defining it in the constructor is a pain aswell. Just use a closure to hide `a`. But you do not have private to an object you have local to a prototype.

Comment: 1. I think this uses a closure. 2. It's not more a pain then all patterns I've seen passing. 3. it's a *create once use many times* prototypal pattern which should be pretty efficient if someone wanted to create, say, 9999 instances. And 4 (bonus!), this works in all browsers.

Comment: @Raynos: *What have you have there is static and private*. Now, how about *There is no such thing as private in JavaScript, so this is not achievable*? It at least resembles contradictory. Could you explain?

Comment: heys this is cool however the variable _a must not be static. is there a way around it? (the only thing i want "static" is the getters/setters not the value itself)

Comment: @Kooilnc The problem is that `A` is not attached to each object. Each object has the same `A` this is not the desired effect.

Comment: @Pacerier: the getters/setters are static I'd say. If you want to use different values for a variable, you'll have to make instance properties. See adjusted script (this.name) for that. You won't need a getter for that, and a setter is a possibility. But such properties are neither static nor private.

Comment: @Raynos: see my answer to Pacerier. `A` is a 'getter'-like method in the prototype of the Human constructor for the private and static variable `a` in that Constructor. So yes, it's invariable for all instances. If he wants variable properties, he should use instance properties, which can be set with a prototypal method.

Comment: @Kooilnc he wants instance properties which are not publicly available. local variables for each instance which are still accesible to the prototype

Comment: @Raynos you can't always get what you want (mmm, sounds familiar somehow). Well GMT+2 timezone, sleeping time. Later!